# Saving expressions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression

Is it possible to save expression, so one doesn't have to retype?

[image]

Comment: Check the drop-down under "recent" or add your (valid) expression to "custom".

Answer (score 10):

This Feature has been introduced with QGIS 3.14, see: https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-add-ability-to-edit-import-and-export-user-expressions

[image]

Once saved, you will find them in "user expressions":

[image]

In older versions, you can only use the ones in "recent" as already mentioned by [@Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387083/select-by-expression-save#comment633948_387083):

[image]